# Linq TakeWhile depending on sum (or aggregate) of elements

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate

I have a list of elements and want to takeWhile the sum (or any aggregation of the elements) satisfy a certain condition. The following code does the job, but i am pretty sure this is not an unusual problem for which a proper pattern should exist.

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
int tmp = 0;
var listWithSum = from x in list
                  let sum = tmp+=x
                  select new {x, sum};
int MAX = 10;
var result = from x in listWithSum
             where x.sum < MAX
             select x.x;
```

Does somebody know how to solve the task in nicer way, probably combining TakeWhile and Aggregate into one query?

Thx

Comment: I am well aware that one shouldn't modify variables as a side effect of a query. If listWithSum is used twice, it will lead to different results if tmp is not initialized in between. Thats one of the reason, why i am convinced that this solution is a bad one!

Comment: var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
int tmp = 0;
int MAX = 10;
var result2 = list.TakeWhile(x => { 
    tmp += x; 
    return tmp < MAX; 
});

Comment: thx Nick. While this is a shorter (and therefore nicer) version, it has the same problem with a side effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you want something like the `Scan` method from [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) (the System.Interactive part) - it's like `Aggregate`, but yields a sequence instead of a single result. You could then do:

```
var listWithSum = list.Scan(new { Value = 0, Sum = 0 },
         (current, next) => new { Value = next,
                                  Sum = current.Sum + next });

var result = listWithSum.TakeWhile(x => x.Sum < MaxTotal)
                        .Select(x => x.Value);
```

([MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) has a [similar operator](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/Scan.cs), btw - but currently it doesn't support the idea of the accumulator and input sequence not being the same type.)

Comment: That seems to be a proper solution - avoiding the side effect on the tmp variable. I wasn't aware of Reactive Extensions.

Another problem i didn't mention above is that by introducing the intermediate result (the anonymous type) the result contains the seed value of the aggregate/scan, which is not part of the initial list.

Comment: @martinweser: If you need to skip the first result, that's easy to do - but I don't *think* you need to with Scan.

Answer (score 0):

I recently solved a similar task and decided to create a separate extension method to avoid third-party libraries:

**Usage:**

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
const int max = 10;

var result = list.TakeWhileAggregate(seed: 0, (accumulator, current) =>
{
    accumulator += current;

    return
    (
        accumulator: accumulator,
        transformedElement: current,
        proceed: accumulator < max
    );
});

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

**Output:** 1, 2, 3

**Extension method:**

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TDest> TakeWhileAggregate<TSource, TAccumulate, TDest>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TAccumulate seed, Func<TAccumulate, TSource, (TAccumulate accumulator, TDest transformedElement, bool proceed)> func)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(func);

        var accumulator = seed;
        foreach (var element in source)
        {
            (accumulator, var transformedElement, var proceed) = func(accumulator, element);
            if (proceed)
            {
                yield return transformedElement;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```