# How can I group in linq based on the number of elements or an aggregate sum at the same time?

Tags: .net, linq, loops

Related [Linq TakeWhile depending on sum (or aggregate) of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699075/linq-takewhile-depending-on-sum-or-aggregate-of-elements)

What I need to do is break a list up into groups smaller than a given number of elements and also with a total size less than a specific figure. Specifically, its to deal with the limits in the Power Automate [Sharepoint Extract Folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#extract-folder) action of 100 files and smaller than 314,572,800 bytes.

My original list contains objects describing files in a zip archive with a property of CompressedSize and what I'm doing right now is:

```
Dim i = 0
Do
    i += 1
    currentSize += entries(i).CompressedSize
Loop Until i = entries.Count - 1 Or target.Count >= MaxZipFiles Or currentSize >= MaxZipBytes
```

I can then `Take` `i-1` items to get the first group `Skip` `i-1` to get any remainder and call the function recursively.

There must be a [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not great with Visual Basic, but here is a C# example that should do what you need.

```
const int maxCount = 100;
const long maxSize = 314572800;

var groups = new List<List<Item>>();

var nextGroup = new List<Item>();

foreach (var item in entries) 
{
    if (nextGroup.Count > maxCount 
        || nextGroup.Sum(x => x.CompressedSize) > maxSize) 
    {
        groups.Add(nextGroup);
        nextGroup = new List<Item>();
    }   
    nextGroup.Add(item);
}

groups.Add(nextGroup);
```

I don't think there is a simpler LINQ way to do this with `GroupBy`.

Recursion may risk hitting a stack overflow for this, and doesn't seem necessary.

You may want to encapsulate this in a new LINQ-style extension method.

Comment: Thanks, but this appears to be essentially the same implementation by interaction rather than recursion - which I agree is a better way to do it. The requery of the new lists rather than just keeping an iteration counter would seem to be less efficient